# jQuery DatePicker Too Large

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've implemented the jQuery datepicker. It seems to be working fine but the calendar is too large.

[jQuery Datepicker http://www.softcircuits.com/Client/datepicker.png](http://www.softcircuits.com/Client/datepicker.png)

The site I'm working on has many layers of stylesheets and parent pages and controls. And I don't seem to be able to isolate what is making it large. (Sorry, the site isn't public.)

It appears the calendar is based on a font size. I tried wrapping my textbox in a div with a smaller font but it seems to ignore that. Is there any way to specify a fixed font size?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

While changing the font size for `.ui-widget` works, I got the best results with the following.

```
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size:11px; }
```

Not only does this seem to do exactly what I need, it is also unlikely to impact any other jquery-ui widgets.

Comment: One word for newcomers: Don't be afraid of using the # (id) selector here. Even if you use multiple components with a date picker on your page, there's only one instance of the date picker floating around (otherwise it would be extremely wasteful). Personally, I tested this solution on a data table of +20 records, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

try setting `font-size` for class `.ui-datepicker`

```
.ui-datepicker {font-size:11px;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/ps5cA/

Comment: I can use `.ui-datepicker { font-size: 1px; }` but it has no effect. It seems to be overridden by `.ui-widget`, which is confusing because it sets a relative size: `1.1em`. Changing this *does* affect it. But only relative to some other font.

Comment: is your css declared after the jquery-ui css in the HTML (`<link>` or `<style>` tags)? Or as a hard coded alternative set `font-size:11px!important`

Comment: It's a huge project and some effort is required to determine everything being included and in what order. It's possible that it was defined before other settings. But I had good luck with setting `#ui-datepicker-div`. See my latest post.

Answer (score 2):

It takes some digging in firebug but I have included one of the versions I use to reduce it. The key is to copy the exact styles from the jQuery-ui CSS file and put them in the head of the page you need them or in a CSS style sheet after the jQuery-ui style sheet.

```
.ui-datepicker {
    padding: 0.1em 0.1em 0;
    width: 11em;
}

.ui-widget {
    font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.ui-datepicker th {
    border: 0 none;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0.2em 0.1em;
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-datepicker th span {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a {
    padding: 0.1em;
}

.ui-datepicker td {
    padding: 0.9px;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-state-highlight {
    height: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, 
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title {
    line-height: 13px;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-title span {
    font-size: 11px;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev span, 
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next span {
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
}

.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-prev, 
.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-next {
    height: 15px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 15px;
}

.ui-datepicker-next-hover .ui-icon {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but oddly this makes the font smaller but the calendar is exactly the same size. It doesn't look like I have Firebug. Chrome has some tools for looking at styles but it doesn't seem to tell me what I need to know.

Comment: Just use the Firefox browser and install the firebug plugin, it allows you to get a better look at the resulting CSS styles ... I will double check if I missed a style somewhere.

Comment: can you post how you are adding the CSS styles? are you able to add the over-ride styles directly to the head of one of the pages

Comment: It's a huge project with many layers of files. I just appended your style to one of the standard CSS files. Perhaps some jquery-ui CSS files were coming after that. At any rate, I had very good results setting `#ui-datepicker-div`. See my latest post.

Comment: Using an old version of jquery (1.11.3) and for me this was the only way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to the site.css worked for me

```
.ui-widget {
    font-size: .7em !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can change "jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css" as follows

```
.ui-widget
{
    font-family: Lucida Grande,Lucida Sans,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.6em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Our calendar was big and ugly looking with hard to click month arrows. It was caused by mismatching versions of the jquery-ui css and jquery-ui js includes.

version numbers must match e.g.

```
jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css
jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js
```

but also needed the css recommended above

```
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size:11px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with mdmullinax. You have to change the font size for the whole class

.ui-datepicker-div { font-size:11px; }

because datepicker is not controlled by id so below change has no impact on size

## ui-datepicker-div { font-size:11px; }

h