# Date picker is too big for the page

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm having the same problem with all date pickers i try. it loads grand in j query when i click on the input box but it is way to big. its gone outside the container and i tried all the solutions people put up and no success. The calender box is t the right size but the days and dates have broken way off the page. can anyone help me.

```
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link href="media-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

.ui-widget { font-family: Lucida Grande, Lucida Sans, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.6em; }

```
</head> 
<body>
    <noscript>
        For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript.
        Here are the <a href="http://www.enable-javascript.com/" target="_blank">
        instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser</a>.
    </noscript>
    <?php include("includes/header.php"); ?><!-- banner_area External File-->               
    <div id="container"><!--Opening Container -->
            <div class="register_login_upload_content"><!-- maincontent-->
            <div class="titleheading"><h3>Upload a Coupon</h3></div><!--Opening submit Header -->
            <div id="uploadformarea"><!-- Opening submit Area -->
            <form method="post" id="couponform" >
                <input type="hidden" name="companyid" id="user_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
                    <label for="adtitle">Choose a title for Coupon:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="adtitle" id="titleinput"  />        
                    <label for="desc">Description:</label>
                    <textarea name="desc" id="coupondesc"></textarea><br />                        
                    <label for="enddate">Select expiry date: </label>
                    <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="enddate" id="couponEndDate"/>                         

                    <input type="hidden" name="uploadtype" value="create_coupon" />                     
                    <input type="submit" name="createcoupon" id="createcoupon" value="Create" class="submit-button"/>
                </form><!-- End of submit Form -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Her is the link [jQuery DatePicker Too Large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6749510/jquery-datepicker-too-large). it might solve your issue. try this,

```
#ui-datepicker-div { font-size:11px; }
```